# How do adverts in a list view affect user behaviour?

Tags: lists

I have a list view of articles on a mobile website and I'd like to position an advert between 2 of the articles in the list. This is something I've seen on forums, where an advert is placed between entries.

I don't know where in the list the advert should go.

These are the options I'm considering:

1. Between the first and second items
2. Between the second and third items

I'm concerned that if I place the ad between the first and second articles, the user might not realise that you can scroll to view more items in the list, increasing the bounce rate.

I'm expecting that putting it after the second or third advert (in a list of approx. 20 items) will mean the user already understands that there is content further down the page.

Is anyone able to offer some guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem and went with placing an ad between header and first article and the first ad between the articles *below* the fold. This way a user is already scrolling down when she sees the second ad. I'd suggest you use a different, smaller ad format for the first ad (e.g. a mobile banner with 60px height) and a bigger ad between the articles below the fold. Ideally the format of the ads differ from the list view items so that they don't get mistaken for ads.

However, as results may differ depending on audience and design, I'd strongly recommend performing an [A/B Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) with the two options you are considering.

Comment: That is as may be, but it's not really an answer to the question. Otherwise "do an AB test" would just be a valid answer to 99% of the posts on this site.

Comment: @JonW true. Enhanced my answer.

Comment: This makes sense. Did you A/B test this when you had the problem? Or was the decision based on best practises of some sort?

Comment: We were porting our desktop site to a responsive layout and had both a mobile banner (height 60px) and a content ad (height 200px) above the fold, thus both taking a lot of visible space. So we chose to put the bigger one below the fold as a) it's a better first impression and b) our content/list invites people to scroll (and generally they do: http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll). But, no, we didn't do an A/B test, although we should have had. Testing such things often has to be canceled when you're running out of time, I'm sure a lot of you guys can relate... ;-)